# My if-statements for the time are not working - getting an error message

Tags: java, if-statement, simpledateformat

I am trying to use if statements to display greetings messages to the user depending on what the current time is. I've already got the current time set up however am unable to use it for the if statements.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        super("Greeting");
        setbounds(200, 200, 200, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
        JTextArea tx = new JTextArea(10,5);
        String myTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        if (myTime < 12am && myTime > 12pm)
            tx.append("Good Morning");
        }
        if (myTime <12am && myTime > 12pm)
            tx.append("Good Afternoon");
        }
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.add(tx);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: `12am` and `12pm` are not valid java identifiers.

Comment: `myTime < 12am && myTime > 12pm`??

Comment: Did you try to Debug your code in IDE?

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz You cannot debug something that won't compile.

Comment: So many syntax errors I can't even

Comment: What do you expect the type of the expression `12am` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your guards, try:

```
if (myTime < twelveAM)
    myGreeting = "Good Morning"
} else {
    myGreeting = "Good Afternoon"
}

tx.append(myGreeting);
```

If myTime is smaller than the value referenced by`twelveAM` then 'Good Morning' will be appended. If myTime is not smaller than the value referenced by `twelveAM`, the process flow will fall through the guard and append 'Good Afternoon'.

Pay special attention to type conversion, that you have to do before making the comparisions in your guard as noted down below in the comments.

Comment: First of all, `if (myTime < 12am)` does  this a valid statement?

Comment: `myTime` is a String and Java will not allow `12am` as an identifier

Comment: He asked specifically about his `if logic`. I provided an answer to that specific question. OP will need to figure out the variable naming and or type conversion problems by himself, his IDE should have told him by now. But as a bonus I corrected the variable naming now too for OP. Of course I could write the entire code for him, but then I want his salary too.

Answer (score 0):

this statement is not right

```
  if (myTime < 12am && myTime > 12pm)
```

you can not compare strings like that, you could get the time in a 24H format, and then parse it to integers in order to compare it.